# Как в Java- классе указать ссылку на библиотеку?

Tags: java, gradle

Я написал в Idea код, в котором используется сторонняя библиотека(которая не входит в стандартную библиотеку Java). Получился один небольшой класс, в котором используются методы и интерфейсы данной либы. Сам проект дальше собирать в jar файл не надо. Нужно запускать данный класс в терминале, компилируя с помощью javac. Проблема в том, что если я просто вытаскиваю этот класс и запускаю таким способом, он ругается,что не знает где брать методы и интерфейсы той самой сторонней библиотеки. Как в этом классе указать на нее ссылку, чтобы он скомпилировался в командной строке?

Comment: Скомпилируйте в идее jar. потом из jar-а извлеките свой класс. jar - это архив zip. В виндовзе можно его переименовать в zip и открыть прямо в проводнике. И ещё. Эта сторонняя библиотека понадобится при запуске программы. Ждём следующего вопроса. А почему не jar? class не намного лучше jar и даже хуже

Comment: если я из jara вытяну только класс он не будет при запуске ругаться на незнакомые методы сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: Будет, обязательно будет. При попытке выполнить. Но я это вроде уже упомянул. У Вас (и вообще ни у кого) никогда не получится class, который не будет ругаться.

Comment: Maven используйте)

Comment: у меня gradle, но в нем до конца не разобрался еще...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`javac` имеет параметр

> -classpath *path* -- Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors

через который задается путь к внешним библиотекам. Пример:

```
javac -classpath .\libs\simple-4.1.21.jar .\src\com\example\MyClass.java
```

Потом так же запускать. Пример:

```
java -classpath .\libs\simple-4.1.21.jar com.example.MyClass
```

Comment: Надо бы пример включения в classpath каталога с библиотекой, jar с бибилиотекой

Comment: Пример добавил.